# Swift - Looping over a struct array

Tags: json, swift, struct

This is so basic, I'm a little embarrassed to ask, but... I'm retrieving some JSON from my server into these structs:

```
struct CategoryInfo: Codable {
    var categoriesResult: [CategoryDetail]
}

struct CategoryDetail: Codable{
    var categoryName: String
    var categoryDescription: String
    var categorySortOrder: Int
    var categoryId: String
}
```

And now I want to loop over CategoryDetail for each of the few-dozen occurrences, saving them into CoreData.  My current attempt looks like this:

```
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let categories = try decoder.decode(CategoryInfo.self, from: data!)
                for category in [CategoryDetail] {
                    //... perform the CoreData storage here
                }
```

But I get the error that CategoryDetail either doesn't conform to Sequence or to IterateProtocol, but when I try to implement those, the solution appears, frankly, too complicated. It's just an array... shouldn't I be able to loop over it without a lot of hoohaw (using that in a technical sense, of course)?

Answer (score 3):

Please take a closer look at your structs

You are decoding the `CategoryInfo` struct

```
let categoryInfo = try decoder.decode(CategoryInfo.self, from: data!)
```

and the categories are in the `categoriesResult` member

```
for category in categoryInfo.categoriesResult {
    //... perform the CoreData storage here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, vadian. I went for a walk and thought through what I was doing wrong - which is exactly as you say.